# Which way better to create vue component (export default vs defineComponent vs new Vue)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

After learning Vue.js lately, i'm pretty match confused about how to write vue component syntax
i keep seeing youtube tutorials, as well as articles, and everyone uses a different approach.

in terms of vue 3
should we use
export default to create a component
or export default defineComponent
or new Vue({

so how to decide the right way on how to create App component and the rest of its child components and pages etc ..

Hopefully my question is clear enough.

Thanks

Comment: They are equivalent. There is no right way. It's perfectly fine to use Options API,  Composition API, with or without typescript, with or without `<script setup>`. Under the hood, they all get translated into pretty much the same thing. Choosing one syntax over another largely depends on project scope and needs (e.g: scalability, size), on team size, team conventions, tooling, and on multiple other factors. Since this tends to be opinionated, it's definitely considered *off-topic* here.

Answer (score 15):

If you need to create multiple components I would highly recommend using [Single File Components](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/single-file-component.html#introduction) (SFC)

#### Here you define a new component as (inside the `<script>` tag):

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  // ...
})
```

(or `export default {}` if not using TypeScript)

#### For the main app component you would do this:

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

OR just like this, if you don't need to extent Vue with vue-router, Vuex etc.

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

Comment: Thanks, So basically if not typescript, no need for defineComponent.

Comment: What about, creating main App component?

Comment: @SystemX I added the main app component to the answer, Consider using a vue scaffolding solution like Vite or vue-cli

Comment: We used vue-cli, i prefer vite, but a lead thinks rollup-sfc is best choice for library component

Comment: Can you please clarify, why you write "recommend using SFC" and then you provide defineComponent-Example which is NOT an SFC with my current understanding?