# In Vue3, how can I access properties similar to those in "beforeRouteEnter" in the Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api

I am working with a Vue project (Composition API, Single-File Components) where I want to access data about the Vue page I came from. I would *really* want to access all the data included in the `beforeRouteEnter` ([about](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#using-the-options-api)) in the Options API, such as previous component names. However, the Navigation Guards in the Composition API don't have any equivalent to the `beforeRouteEnter` guard.

I have tried to add a separate `<setup>` segment above the main `<setup script>` segment, but I don't know how to access the values I have in the separate setup from my original setup:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from) {
        ...
    },
});
</script>

<script lang="ts" setup>
// How to access to/from in here?
</script>
```

My questions are then:

1. **How can I access the value from the top setup segment into my regular `<setup>`?**
2. **Is this even an accepted Vue pattern?** If not, is there any other way to get more information about the from-path than *just* the path itself (e.g. names of previous components) using the Composition API?

Comment: You were right, `beforeRouteEnter` does run before `setup()`. So [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-router-forked-8f47wy?file=/src/views/Home.vue)'s something that works.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, and I can access the values as I wanted. If you can post it as an answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beforeRouteEnter` is not available in `setup()`. But it's a special hook, which is run before `setup()` (unlike most other hooks), so you could pass data from it to `setup()` using an external store:

**routerStore.ts**

```
import { reactive } from 'vue'
export const state = reactive({
  from: null,
  to: null
})
```

**View**:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { state } from './routeStore'
export default defineComponent({
  beforeRouteEnter(from, to) {
    Object.assign(state, { from, to })
  }
})
</script>
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { state } from './routeStore'
console.log(state)
</script>
```

Comment: But should it not be possible to save the data from `beforeRouteEnter` as well?

Comment: Not sure if I understand where `beforeRouteEnter` is in this diagram. If this is about mounting, wouldn't that mean that `beforeRouteEnter` has ran before this?

Comment: @Anna, note I've removed my previous comment, as I completely replaced the initial content of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with `script setup`, it is sugar syntax for the body of `setup` function, which is called on route component instantiation, while `beforeRouteEnter` hook is supposed to be triggered before component instantiation.

`script setup` covers only the most common cases, any any other it should be coupled or replaced with `script`:

```
<script>
export default {
  beforeRouteEnter() { ... }
}
</script>

<script setup>...</script>
```

As long as `beforeRouteEnter` is used for asynchronous route initialization, it can be replaced with asynchronous setup, which is supported by Vue router:

```
<script setup>
await ...
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question. `<script setup lang="ts">` is equivalent to

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    ...
    return { .. }
  }
})
</script>
```

If you find you are incapable of doing sthg, consider use the latter syntax, eg. manually register local components with `defineComponent`:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { computed, defineComponent, onMounted, ref, type PropType, watch } from 'vue'
import { type NavigationGuardNext, type Route } from 'vue-router'
import { onBeforeRouteUpdate } from 'vue-router/composables'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'CompB',
  metaInfo: { title: 'Title 1' },
  beforeRouteEnter (to: Route, from: Route, next: NavigationGuardNext) {
    if (! someGateValue })) {
      next({ name: 'error.403' })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  },
  components: { ChildCompA },
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {
    user: {
      type: Object as PropType<User>,
      required: true
    },
    showModal: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  emits: ['updated'],
  setup (props, { emit }) {
    const userList = ref<User[]>([])

    const visibleUserList = computed<User[]>(() => userList.value.filter(u => u.age > 5))

    ... 

    onBeforeRouteUpdate((to: Route, from: Route, next: NavigationGuardNext) => {
      if (! someGateValue })) {
        next({ name: 'error.403' })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    })

    return { userList, visibleUserList }
  }
})
</script>
```

Here are ALL THE *ComponentOptions* that can be attached to the powerful `defineComponent`.

[vue doc - definecomponent](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#definecomponent)

[vue source code - *ComponentOptions*](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/main/src/types/options.ts)

---

in [vuejs.org/api](https://vuejs.org/api/), I see plenty of *script setup API* eg `defineXxxx` are just unnecessary sugar  , which could be simply attached to to the powerful `defineComponent` as *ComponentOptions*

```
defineProps // props: { }
defineEmits // emits: []
defineOptions // other options eg inheritAttrs  https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html
```

other doc:
https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview `defineComponent`

related:
[Which way better to create vue component (export default vs defineComponent vs new Vue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66956931/which-way-better-to-create-vue-component-export-default-vs-definecomponent-vs-n)